# How to configure others attributes on gmaps4rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails and really enjoying it, but, I missed setting some properties, such as:

- scrollwheel
- zoomControl
- zoomControlOptions

How could these be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a dedicated callback in the gem to trigger custom settings.

You could do this:

```
<%# your call to gmaps4rails here %>

//important: this must be AFTER the call to gmaps4rails so that the Gmaps4Rails class is known.
<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() {
    Gmaps4Rails.map.setOptions({
      scrollwheel: false,
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: whatever_you_need
    }):
  };
</script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why are you adding the "ruby" tag to questions that can't be answered by non-rails people? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65238/do-rails-questions-have-to-have-the-tag-ruby and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71263/ruby-on-rails-questions-being-tagged-with-ruby-incorrectly

Comment: Please tell me it's not related to wanting to earn more badges!

Comment: :) Badges are not a motivation. I did this because I think creating a gem (these questions are related to a gem of mine), require mostly ruby skills. I seldom change tags but this seemed to be a good representation of my open source involvement (and a fair retribution for my work).

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: see my answer above :)

Comment: That creating a gem requires Ruby skills is not relevant. Otherwise, all Rails questions would be tagged Ruby, and most Ruby questions would be tagged C. Also, Stack Overflow is not for "retribution" of your work. (Also, I do not think it means what you think it means).

Comment: FYI, you recently gained three badges in the same day through retagging: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110675/tag-badge-triggered-by-retagging-potential-for-abuse

Answer (score 0):

hey this is the code for controls jsut put in your javascript tags and enjoy the controls

```
function initialize() {
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
  mapTypeControl: true,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
  },
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
  },
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                              myOptions);
```

}

here is the running example of this code having all controls
[example of google map controls](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-options.html)

yep google maps are fun to play, just go through these examples, you will be an expert brother i tell you ;)
[google map examples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/index.html)

for complete google map documentation visit this link  below, happy Googling
[Google Map API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)

Comment: theGame, I would like to know how to do this using the gem gmaps4rails.